# authentication issue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have login page and below one is my authentication code. when I run in my browser I am getting injector unpresent.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 bgcolor" ng-controller="log"> 
 <div class="txtbox col-md-12">     
   <input type="text" placeholder="User ID" class="txtchar">
 </div>
 <div class="txtbox col-md-12">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="txtchar">
  </div>
  <div class="fgpwd col-md-12">
    <label>Forget Password</label>
    <span><button class="logbtn" ng-click="logclick(userCred)">Login</button></span>        
  </div>
</div>
```

AngularJs: `

```
app.factory('auth',['$http','session',function($http,session) {
var authService = {};

authService.login = function(userCred) {
$http.post('//localhost:5000/login',userCred)
.then(
  function successCallback(response){
    console.log(response);
  session.create(response.data.id);
  var user = response.data;
 if (user [user.username && user.password]) {
 var userCred = user[user.username && user.password];
 if (userCred.username == user.username && userCred.password == user.password) {
    $scope.csp_user = response.data;
} else {
    console.log('Error');
  }
 }
});
};

authService.isAuthenticated = function() {
 return {
 isAuthenticated : false,
 user : null
 }
};

return authService;
}]);         

app.controller('log', function($scope, $http,auth) {
$scope.logForm = {};

$scope.userCred = {
    username : '',
    password : ''
};

    /*-----Form Submition-----*/

$scope.logclick = function(){
    auth.isAuthenticated = true;
    if (isAuthenticated = true) {
        $scope.go('/main.html');
    } else {
        console.log('error');
        return;
    }
};

    /*-----Calling Factory Function-----*/

$scope.login = function(userCred) {
    auth.isAuthenticated = true;
    auth.login(function(user) {
        console.log('success');
    },function(error) {
        console.log("error");
    });
}   
});
```

When I run the above code I am getting **Unknown provider: sessionProvider <- session <- auth** . Please let me know where I am going wrong. Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `session` in your factory as inject not found in your application, maybe you didn't add the file of it

Answer (score 0):

This is not big problem, but it's good if you know about `injection`

```
app.factory('factory', function(a, b){

})
```

in this factory, the `app` should has `a` and `b` too, for example `a` is another `factory` and `b` is `service`

```
app.factory('a', function() { })

app.service('b', function() { })
```

missing each of them make application stop, and you will get provider error.